# Hydride Donating Ability

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reaction-control

We know that some compounds can donate $\ce{H-}$ anion to attain stability. What are the conditions under which it occurs and what should be the extent of stability of the product for this pathway to be viable?

Comment: Only some anionic intermediates do that AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many compounds are good hydride donors, if it results in carbonyl bond formation or extended conjugation. Sometimes, a compound can donate H- ion if it results in stable pi bond formation.
(e.g. Tertiary butyl carbanion)

Comment: t-butyl **carbocation** won't release $\ce{H-}$.

Comment: @orthocresol.  I meant Carbonion

Comment: Ok. I guess you mean something like tBuLi? Never seen that acting as a hydride donor... but I might learn something new here...